# How to use SMTP to send email in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, email, ionic2, smtp, ionic3

I'm trying to send email by using Gmail SMTP. I checked so many solutions but nothing work.

Today I found this site https://www.smtpjs.com/ that may help me to solve my issue but I need help to know where should I put this HTML line:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"></script>
```

Then how can I import **Email** in my **home.ts** to use this code:

```
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password");
```

Comment: Are you try cordova-plugin-email-composer plugin.

Comment: No, I checked email-composer plugin. Its just open mail apps

Comment: have you got proper solution. which send mail from application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fistly if you have button to send like that

```
<button id="SendMessage">SEND MAIL</button>
```

put the code below under the page  ( i used also jquery to do it )

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"></script>
<script>
$("#SendMessage").on("click",function(){

Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password",
function done(message) { alert("This area for after mail send.") }
);

});
</script>
```